# Returning different types of arrays from a lambda expression in F#

Tags: arrays, f#, lambda, types, record

i have a List of records

```
type Item = { Color : string; Size : int}
let itemList = [{Color="Red"; Size=1};
                {Color="Green"; Size=2};
                {Color="Blue"; Size=3};]
```

I am looking to get turn my list of records into an array of values like
[|"Red";"Green";"Blue"|] or [|1;2;3|]

I can sorta get there like this

```
type ItemType =
| Color of string
| Size of int

type ItemEnum =
| C
| S

let GetProp x y =
match x with
| C -> List.toArray y |> Array.map(fun x -> ItemType.Color(x.Color))
| S -> List.toArray y |> Array.map(fun x -> ItemType.Size(x.Size))
```

but when I call `GetProp S itemList` I get back [|Size 1; Size 2; Size 3|]. Useful but not exactly what I'm looking for.

I've tried the following

```
let GetProp2 x y : 'a[] =
match x with
| Color -> List.toArray y |> Array.map(fun x -> x.Color)
| Size -> List.toArray y |> Array.map(fun x -> x.Size)
```

but it doesn't like the two different return types.

I'm open to suggestions on different (more functional?) ways of doing this and would appreciate your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A custom variant type is indeed the way to go here (and generally wherever you need a type that is "either X or Y"). However, as defined, your function looks like it might return an array in which `Color` and `Size` are mixed, but in practice it seems that you only want it to return one or the other. If so, this is best reflected in the types:

```
type Items =
| Colors of string[]
| Sizes of int[]

let GetProp x ys =
match x with
| C -> Colors [| for y in ys -> y.Color |]
| S -> Sizes [| for y in ys -> y.Size |]
```

By the way, is there any particular reason why you use array for return type here, rather than the usual lazy sequence (`seq`)?

Comment: the array is the argument type required by the external lib I'm using next.  How would I go from List of records to the seq of the particular value?

Comment: Any list is already a seq, and so is any array. In .NET terms, seq is `IEnumerable<T>`. If you need to make an array or a list out of any random seq (and possibly a lazy one), then `Seq.toArray` and `Seq.toList` will do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You can use active patterns to see your data form few points of view:

```
let (|AsColor|) (v: Item list) = [| for i in v -> i.Color |];;

let (|AsSize|) (v: Item list) = [| for i in v -> i.Size |];;

match itemList,itemList with
  |AsColor ca, AsSize sa -> printfn "%A; %A" ca sa;;
```

Comment: I hadn't been exposed to the active pattern yet. Interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Go go gadget Array Comprehensions!

```
> [| for a in itemList do yield a.Size |];;
val it : int [] = [|1; 2; 3|]
> [| for a in itemList do yield a.Color |];;
val it : string [] = [|"Red"; "Green"; "Blue"|]
```

You don't need an intermediate `ItemType` or `ItemEnum` data structure.

Comment: That won't help him, as he's trying to write a _single_ function that is returning arrays of _different_ element types, depending on its arguments.