# Getting a typed array from a discriminate union of different types of arrays in F#

Tags: arrays, f#, discriminated-union

If I have a discriminate union of different types of arrays how can i convert them to their 'actual' types?

```
type ItemStuff = 
   | Colors of string[]
   | Sizes of int[]

let foo = Sizes [|1;2;3|]
```

After running the above when I get the value of foo I see:

```
val foo : ItemStuff = Sizes [|1;2;3|]
```

How can I get an actual array of int's from foo?  Am I just missing some syntax that allows me access to something like 
`foo.[2]`?  I cannot enumerate through foo so I wasn't able to use map.  I could write a member for ItemStuff that returns a properly typed array for each different type of array i am returning, but that just didn't seem right?

What are my best approaches here?

Here is what I ended up doing. any ideas on better ways to do it?

```
type ItemProp =
| Colors of string[]
| Sizes of int[]
| Quants of int[]
member this.GetColors() =
   match this with
   | Colors (stringArray) ->
       stringArray
   | _ -> null
member this.GetIntArr() =
   match this with
   | Sizes (intArray) | Quants (intArray) ->
       intArray
   |_ -> null

foo.GetIntArr()
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a DU for that? class or struct may be more appropriate.

Comment: You've asked a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932124/returning-different-types-of-arrays-from-a-lambda-expression-in-f), and I sort of get the feeling that you're asking the wrong question. Instead of "what is the syntax to do X", start at a higher level and say "I want to write a program which does Y, here's what I have so far, is there are a more idiomatic way to do it in F#?"

Comment: Juliet- This question is similar to the extent that it extends my previous question. I could have done earlier in c# but I'm using this as an exercise to learn about f# and functional programming. While I appreciate your advice I feel that if my question had been "I have a comma delimited list with each line containing a string, an int, and a float.  How do I 1) transform the various elements into typed arrays to be passed as arguments into external libs and 2) keep the objects around in some useful form (i.e struct, record, etc) and 3) all in a f# way" my answers would have been less helpful.

Comment: You might have missed the point. Why not use a record instead like advised by Ray Vernagus? (if it's just for storing some data).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How can I get an actual array of int's from foo?

That's the actual problem since `foo` is just said to have type `ItemStuff`. So it *doesn't have to* contain a `Sizes`-value at all - it could be a `Colors` as well.

Hence your programm has to decide here

```
let getIntArray = function
    | Sizes arr -> arr
    | Colors _  -> failwith "Given value doesn't contain an int array`
```

`getIntArray foo` will work properly but `getIntArray (Colors [||])` will fail, but from type-level both are valid.

Note that if you're completely sure that the operation will succeed, you can use pattern-matching directly:

```
let getIntArray (Sizes arr) = arr
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'd use pattern matching since you won't know if an `ItemStuff` holds colors or sizes.  If you definitely know that you've got a `Sizes` instance, you can do something like:

```
let (Sizes arr) = foo
```

to pull the array back out.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not actually representing an either/or scenario (Colors OR Sizes), consider using a [Record type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184%28VS.100%29.aspx) here:

```
type ItemStuff = 
    { Colors : string[];
      Sizes : int[] } with
    static member Default = { Colors = [||]; Sizes = [||] }

let foo = { ItemStuff.Default with Sizes = [|1;2;3|] }
printfn "%A" foo.Colors    // [||]
printfn "%A" foo.Sizes     // [|1; 2; 3|]
printfn "%d" foo.Sizes.[2] // 3
```

Comment: Thanks for this Ray.  It hadn't occurred to me until I read your post to add members to my DU that would take care of delivering the typed arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can also return an option type with None if the discriminated union wasn't a `Sizes`.

```
let getIntArray item =
    match item with
    | Sizes(i) -> Some(i)
    | _        -> None
```

But keep in mind that at the end in F# a function always transforms an input data type into an output data type, or a function just makes a side effect (printing something on screen or inserting data into an array).

So, for example, if you just want to print the `Sizes` (or nothing if it's a `Colors`) it will be shorter to write a new function for that purpose:

```
let printSizes item =
    match item with
    | Sizes(i) -> printfn "%A" i
    | _        -> ()
```

instead of:

```
let getIntArray item =
    match item with
    | Sizes(i) -> Some(i)
    | _        -> None

let res = getIntArray foo

(function | Some(i) -> printfn "%A" i | _ -> ()) res
```